# Too few parameters, expected 1? error access

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I am getting the above error whilst running this commmand:

```
   CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE VolunteerDetails " & _
   " SET FirstName=" & Me.frst_Name_txt & _
   ", LastName='" & Me.lst_Name_txt & "'" & _
   ", PostalCode='" & Me.pst_Code_txt & "'" & _
   " WHERE VolsID=" & Me.vol_ID_txt
```

Can anyone explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: Are those values coming from textboxes? If so, you need the `.text` identifier on the end of the textbox name.

Comment: -1 This is the second question you've tagged with both mysql and ms-access. Do not use inappropriate tags for your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the FirstName value. It seems to be a string and so you need to put your value inside single quotes

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE VolunteerDetails " & _
" SET FirstName='" & Me.frst_Name_txt & "'" & _
", LastName='" & Me.lst_Name_txt & "'" & _
", PostalCode='" & Me.pst_Code_txt & "'" & _
" WHERE VolsID=" & Me.vol_ID_txt
```

Said that, please read about [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and [Parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Your code, as is, it is very weak and could fail simply if someone types a LastName like `O'Malley` (the single quote breaks your string concatenation)

As pointed by a comment above, I suppose that these variables are not TextBoxes but just string variables. If these are TextBoxes then, the value to set the field to comes from the Text property of the TextBox. Something like

```
" SET FirstName='" & Me.frst_Name_txt.Text & "'"
```

Comment: Yes! That works a charm, I did not know that about strings, +1 to you sir!

Comment: @user2799788 **accept** the answer, dont just upvote